# Change the editor Xcode 4 uses for property lists?

Tags: iphone, ios, editor, xcode4, plist

I like [PlistEdit Pro](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/development_tools/plisteditpro.html) way better than the default plist editor that comes with Xcode 4.  Is there any way to tell Xcode 4 to always use PlistEdit Pro an an alternate editor for my property lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First set PlistEdit Pro as the default application to open property list files. You can do this from the Finder by selecting a .plist file and bringing up the Info panel.

After that, the "Open with external editor" option will be available when you right-click on a .plist file in Xcode 4's project navigator.