# objective c when to use NSDictionary instead of NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm in a dilemma in terms of which of the two I should use. I will be retrieving a group of data via a restful API (returns json) and I'm not sure how I should store them before I display it on my UI View Table.

eg.

```
{"Events":[{"Id":5,"Name":"Event 1 2013"},{"Id":6,"Name":"Event 2 2013"}]}
```

I've been reading tutorials and some would use NSMutableArrays while some would use NSMutableDictionary.

How should I go about it?

**BTW: I'm displaying the data on UI View table that will redirect the user to another page when tapped and if they decide to go back will have to show the previous view without reloading (uses UinavigationController)**

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Also, just to give you an idea on what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to follow this tutorial on splitting the data I get into section headers. On this tutorial it's using NSDictionary.

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/

If I use NSArray, would that affect the performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In NSArray - every item in the collection has an integer index, so there is an explicit order to the items. When you're retrieving/replacing/removing the stored object from the NSARRY,you need to specify the corresponding object index of that stored object.

NSDictionary - derived from the word called entry. Each entry consists of one object that represents the key and a second object that is that key’s value. Within a dictionary, the keys are unique. That is, no two keys in a single dictionary are equal (as determined by isEqual:).When you're retrieving the object from the dictionary you need to specify the key value for the [objectForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey%3a) 
Whenever if you're parsing the plist then NSDictionary would be ideal.You can refer [apple's document here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more explanation about NSDictionary.Happy coding :)

Comment: This is entirely plagiarized from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9416283/19679

Answer (score 3):

The lookup times on NSDictionaries are faster than on NSArrays.  That's one of the main advantages. Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html) to the Apple documentation.

Comment: Translating dictionary keys to indexes in a table row is much more difficult than using an array however and adds another layer of complexity and time to determine the proper key....

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you need to access data in an indexed fashion (like you need to for rows in a table) then you should use an array because you can access any specific index using `indexOfObject:`

Now, if you have a lot of information for each row then you should have an array of either custom objects or an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Let's say I would get about 50 - 100 per request was wondering is it ok if I just use the NSArray and just limit the amount of data the API sends and just have the user tap a button to load the next set? Instead of using NSDictionary?

Comment: Yes, you can use `NSArray`'s with much larger data sets than that and it works quite well.

Comment: Awesome good to know. Btw, any chance you can point me to some examples on how to arrange multiple NSArrays so that it will be placed on a UITableView divided in sections?

Comment: Sure, usually you just create an array for section 0, one for section 1, etc.  Then you create one "master" array with all of the different arrays for each section.  Then, to access section 2, row 3 you would use:  `[[masterArray objectAtIndex:2] objectAtIndex:3];`.  If you need a more specific example, ask another question with the details!

Comment: done! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503112/objective-c-dynamic-nsdictionary-for-ui-table-view-divided-by-section-headers

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary are always faster than Arrays. Dictionary maps keys to objects, just like a hash table. It's an associative array.

For searching some value you need to iterate for arrays, in dictionary you retrieve it by key.

If you want the collection to be in some sorted order or arrival order then Array is the proper type for you.

Dictionary lacks when you end up getting two same keys.

And I feel good to use arrays for tableViews as I can directly associate row to index.