# Objective C Dynamic NSDictionary for UI Table View divided by Section Headers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

So this is based off of my question here

[objective c when to use NSDictionary instead of NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493725/objective-c-when-to-use-nsdictionary-instead-of-nsarray#comment20201177_14493725)

Apologies for the noob questions. I just started learning objective c and I'm really confused.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    headers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Header Section 1 (H1)", @"Header Section 2 (H2)", nil];
    events = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"H1 Content 1", @"H1 Content 2", nil];
    myInfo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"H2 Content 1", @"H2 Content 2", @"H2 Content 3", nil];

    menuDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for(NSString *event in events){
        [menuDetails setValue:event forKey:@"Header Section 1 (H1)"];
    }

    for(NSString *info in myInfo){
        [menuDetails setValue:info forKey:@"Header Section 1 (H2)"];
    }
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [[menuDetails allKeys] count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[[menuDetails allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

1. Wanted to limit this for the First Section but not on the 2nd section

   ```
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       return 5;
   }
   ```
2. So I'm not really sure how to make this dynamic when I try to fill up the cells with this method. I'm not really sure how to make sure it selects the "Key" of the section the specific cell is at (blocked line) :

---

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"OptionCellIdentifier";

        MenuOptionTableCell *cell = (MenuOptionTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil){
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OptionCellIdentifier" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        NSDictionary *menuItem = [[menuDetails valueForKey:[[[menuDetails allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.optionName.text = [menuItem objectForKey:@"Events"];

        return cell;
    }
```

EDIT: GAAAHHH, the formatting is killing me. It won't get inside the code markup

This is where Idk what to do:

> cell.optionName.text = [menuItem objectForKey:@"Events"];

So what I wanted to happen is:

- Section Header 1

  1. H1 Content 1
  2. H1 Content 2
- Section Header 1

  1. H2 Content 1
  2. H2 Content 2
  3. H1 Content 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by first creating a "MyMenuSection" object as follows;

```
@interface MyMenuSection : NSObject {
    NSString *title;
    NSMutableArray *rows;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *rows;

@end

@implementation

@synthesize title;
@synthesize rows;

@dealloc {
    [title release];
    [rows release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Then in your viewDidLoad (or wherever you decide to inialize/assign the data) you would do this;

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray menuDetails = [NSMutableArray array];

    MyMenuSection section = [[MyMenuSection alloc] init];
    section.title = @"Header Section 1 (H1)";
    [section.rows addObjects:@"H1 Content 1", @"H1 Content 2", nil];
    [menuDetails addObject:section];
    [section release];

    section = [[MyMenuSection alloc] init];
    section.title = @"Header Section 2 (H2)";
    [section.rows addObjects:@"H2 Content 1", @"H2 Content 2", @"H2 Content 3", nil];
    [menuDetails addObject:section];
    [section release];

    self.menuDetails = menuDetails;
    [menuDetails release];

}
```

Then your UITableView data and delegate callbacks would look like this;

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [menuDetails count];
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return [[(MyMenuSection *)[menuDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] rows] count];
    }
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [(MyMenuSection *)[menuDetails objectAtIndex:section] title];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"OptionCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OptionCellIdentifier" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.optionName.text = (NSString *)[[(MyMenuSection *)[menuDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] rows] objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;

}
```

YMMV, Happy Coding

Comment: quick question, dont you have to worry about the numberOfRowsInSection? I wanted to limit the number of rows displayed on the first section that's why.

Comment: oh and I'm getting an error on the "titleForHeaderInSection". It would throw [MainOptionsViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ......

Comment: I updated the answer with this required method included.  I return a hard "2" here, but set it to whatever you may like for the number of rows in section 0.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're over thinking things here. My biggest recommendation here would be to get rid of all your separate arrays and start nesting them within each other. By that I mean make menuItems a NSArray of your arrays events and myInfo.

This will make it easier for you later on to get your dynamic row count using .count.

example:

```
events = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"H1 Content 1", @"H1 Content 2", nil];
myInfo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"H2 Content 1", @"H2 Content 2", @"H2 Content 3", nil];

NSArray *menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:events, myInfo, nil];
```

Now when you call the array in

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray objectAtIndex: section];
    return tempArray.count;
}
```

As for pulling the cell names later on.

```
cell.optionName.text = [[menuItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: so where do I set up the section header names?

Comment: You could either have a separate array for that, or you could turn the menuItems array into a dictionary. Use your objects as shown above and the keys for your section titles.