# set variable to 'YES' for each edited Textfield using UIControlEventEditingChanged

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want to keep track of edited textfields. I would like to store every edited textfield in a variable. Then when the user press the 'save' button it updates the edited textfield in the database.

I want to know how i can, in "(void)textChanged:' specify what textfield is being changed and then store it in a variable (array?). Then i want to pick out the edited textfield names from the array and execute a -(void).

Example:
 * testTextfield gets edited.
 * Add the edited textfieldname and store it in an Array
 * Extract the edited textfields from the array
 * Execute a -(Void) with the edited textfields

.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allEditedTextfields;
```

.m file:

```
[testTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Here i want to identify what textfield got edited and store it in the Array.

```
 -(void)textChanged:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [allEditedTextfields addObject:textField.text];
}
```

This is when i press the 'save' button:

```
-(IBAction)btnSaveHorse:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Array - %@", allEditedTextfields);
}
```

And when i press the save button it says (Array - (null))

-(void)textChanged: will be executed everytime a new letter or number is being typed.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you probably don't want to add an object to an array each time something is typed in a text field. What you might want to do is use an `NSMutableDictionary` to store values for each text field.

You could give each text field a unique `tag` either in the interface file or in code using:

```
yourObject.tag = 1; //Or whatever
```

Then, you'd need an `NSMutableDictionary`. You must initialize the dictionary (I'm assuming you didn't initialize your array, which is why you were getting `(null)`).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *allEditedTextfields; //.h

allEditedTextfields = [NSMutableDictionary new]; //viewDidLoad of .m
```

Then, inside your `textChanged:` function, use the `tag` as the key of a `NSNumber`-wrapped boolean indicating that your text field has been edited. This will also ensure that there aren't any duplicates (it'll overwrite anything at the existing key if there is anything):

```
-(void)textChanged:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [allEditedTextfields setObject:@TRUE forKey:@(textField.tag)];
}
```

Lastly, whenever you're ready to upload your data to a database, just loop through the dictionary and use `viewWithTag` to get the text field.

```
for (NSNumber *key in allEditedTextfields) { //Loop through all keys

    if ([[dict objectForKey:key] boolValue] == TRUE) { //See if it was edited

        UITextField *tField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:[key intValue]];
        //save your data using tField.text          
    }
}

[allEditedTextfields removeAllObjects]; //Remove the objects when you're done so it doesn't upload the same ones next time unless they're edited again
```

Comment: I will definitely try this out!! Thank you so much!
What is the difference between an Array and a NSDictionary?

Comment: And to answer your question, an array is basically a sequence of objects, while a dictionary has objects that are accessible by "keys" instead of indexes. For a thorough answer, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416053/whats-the-difference-between-a-dictionary-and-an-array).

Comment: Should i still use "[testTextField addTarget:self..." for each textfield aswell?

Comment: For the `textChanged:` function, yes.

Comment: But, if i change the text from "test" to "testing" in a textfield. Then it will add 3 objects in the NSDictionary, or am i wrong?

Comment: Like I said in the answer, it will only have one entry per `UITextField` `tag`. So, if each text field has a unique `tag`, it'll be fine. The `setObject:forKey:` function of `NSMutableDictionary` replaces anything that's already at that `key`, so there will only be one object for each text field.

Comment: When it come to some being integers and some strings. How can i identify the difference?

Comment: Please ask that in a different question, it is not relevant to this thread.

Comment: I don't understand how i should update it to the database. How will i make so the for-loop executes the right update code to the right column in the row into the database? I mean, if i edit textfield playerName and playerScore. How will the database know which one to update?